# Error: Class in different directory than declared

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working in Rational Clear case. 
When I import maven project in my local system fom clear case and install, it installs successfully and all the java classes are compiling.
When I try to work directly from clear case in Eclipse, and I try to install the same project, I get error in compiling all the java classes.

Few lines of Error:

```
 Error building bundle <groupId>:<artifactId>:bundle:2.1.6 : Class in different directory than declared. Path from class name is services/helper/impl/DefaultDroolsHelper.class but the path in the jar is services/helper/impl/defaultdroolshelper.class from Jar:dot
    [ERROR] Error building bundle <groupId>:<artifactId>:bundle:2.1.6 : Class in different directory than declared. Path from class name is services/helper/impl/DefaultDroolsHelperFactory.class but the path in the jar is services/helper/impl/defaultdroolshelperfactory.class from Jar:dot
    [ERROR] Error(s) found in bundle configuration
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 52.422s
    [INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 08 04:23:29 EDT 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/49M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.4:bundle (default-bundle) on project wss-services: Error(s) found in bundle configuration -> [Help 1]
```

After installation, in target folder, the two list are generated:
createdfiles.lst

```
entities\output\clientenrichmenttype$clienttrader.class
   entities\output\dateadjustmenttype.class
   entities\dtcc\valuation\output\collateralizedtype.class
   entities\triresolve\output\objectfactory.class
```

But inputfiles.lst:

```
 entities\dtcc\leireplay\output\SecoryAssetClassType.java
    entities\dtcc\valuation\output\VerificationType.java
    entities\dtcc\leireplay\output\package-info.java
    entities\output\BlockTradeOrAllocationLegType.java
```

Please try to resolve this issue.
Thanks,
Ravish

Comment: i can see no difference, except the case-sensitive D in calss name: Default and default
`services/helper/impl/DefaultDroolsHelper.class`
`services/helper/impl/defaultdroolshelper.class`
same this for `DefaultDroolsHelperFactory`, so make sure to make them similar

Comment: @ravish4596 How are you importing the project in eclipse?

Comment: @Skizzo Right click on Import and selected the respective project from the view in clear case.

Comment: @Yazan I think I am getting error because of case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The file name on Windows was created in small letters evidently, though the class name is mixed-case. This works because Windows makes no distinction.

However ported to Linux or OSX, or packed in zip format as .jar/.ear/.war one has a problem.

Correcting the file name is a bit hairy; rename it to something else, and then rename it correctly. Furthermore your versions control system may hickup too.

---

Made a small utility [CheckJavaFiles](http://pastebin.com/rV3k8azb) correcting wrong case of java files under Windows.
Package names it does not check. But too much effort for something maybe unneeded; they general are small letters.

Comment: I have a lot of java classes. And, all are getting same problems. It's not so easy to edit all and rename it again. Please advice me some other solution. One more point, I am working in remote machine.

Comment: Okay wrote a tool that does a rename. I hope it works. Pass top directory as parameter.

Comment: I want to confirm whether it's a clear case issue or my eclipse issue. Can you please advice on this? Because, When I import project from clear case to my local system and install, it works fine. But, If I directly connects to my view project and try to install, I get this type of error.

Comment: Is the problem indeed that the file names loose their mixed case? I do not understand the exact problem. Network? FAT32 formatted disk? Copy script? Good luck exploring that. If you found a solution add an answer here. Till then, feel free to contact me.